# Generate native html table in ZK Java

Tags: java, model-view-controller, zk

Im learning how to program in java using Eclipse and ZK Studio.
I'm doing a project that requires me to use xhtml elements in a ZK project and also ZK elements inside those. Purpose is to generate a html table with zk elements inside it BUT to do that in a java controller.

My question is how would you generate the table body from the java controller with multiple rows and with zk checkboxes and checkbox labels attached to it?
Examples below:

The code for the .zul would look like this:

```
<zk>
<window border="none" xmlns:h="xhtml" xmlns:xk="zk" apply="controller.McC">
<div>
    <h:table>
      <h:thead id="thHead">
        <h:tr>
          <h:th>
            <zk:label value="Column title">
          </h:th>
        </h:tr>
      </h:thead>
      <h:tbody>
        <h:tbody id="tbody"/>
      </h:tbody>
    </h:table>
</div>
</window>
</zk>
```

What i want the table to generate a tbody from the java controller, when i, for example press a button and that would generate something similar to this, but from the controller code:

```
<h:tbody id="tbody">
  <h:tr>
    <h:td>
      <zk:checkbox label="Row 1">
    </h:td>
  </h:tr>
  <h:tr>
    <h:td>
      <zk:checkbox label="Row 2">
    </h:td>
  </h:tr>
 <h:tr>
    <h:td>
      <zk:checkbox label="Row 2">
    </h:td>
  </h:tr>
</h:tbody>
```

I think it has something to do with generating the checkboxes, setting its label to a value, generating a Td, setting the parent of the checkbox to td, generating a Tr, setting the parent of Td's to Tr's and the applying the entire row to the tbody using the tbody id. Not sure how to do it though.

Comment: where is your java code

Comment: I don't have it. That's why i'm asking how would 1 write such a thing? Maybe something like private Tbody tbody; tbody.getChildren.clear(); Checkbox cb = new Checkbox; cb.SetLabel("Row 1");Tr tr = new Tr(); Td td = new Td(); td.setParent(Tr); cb.setParent(td); tbody.appendChild(Tr);

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to add native HTML into your code you could use this :

```
HtmlNativeComponent n = new HtmlNativeComponent("html", "First part", "second part");
```

Small explication :

First String (html) stands for the tag where your content is wrapped in.
Second String (First part) stands for your content **before** any children.
Third String (second part) stands for your content after the children you maybe add later.

[Documentation of the class can be found here.](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/HtmlNativeComponent.html#HtmlNativeComponent(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

If you want to create it from code, you can work like the swing way, like your comment already suggested.
For actions you need to add eventlisteners to the components.